# Flutter build error concerning CodeSign on macOS

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, dart

To build an application for macOS with Flutter, from the terminal I executed
`flutter run -d macOS`, but the build failed. Here is a part of the log of the build with the `--verbose` option that I think is relevant.

```
[ +166 ms] CodeSign [the directory of the project]/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/mail_app.app (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[        ]     cd [the directory of the project]/macos
[        ]     Signing Identity:     "-"
[        ]     /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements
[the directory of the project]/build/macos/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug/Runner.build/mail_app.app.xcent --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der
[the directory of the project]/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/mail_app.app
[  +23 ms] [the directory of the project]/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/mail_app.app: code object is not signed at all
[        ] In subcomponent: [the directory of the project]/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/mail_app.app/Contents/Frameworks/App.framework
[        ] Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
[  +10 ms] ** BUILD FAILED **
[        ] The following build commands failed:
[        ]  CodeSign [the directory of the project]/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/mail_app.app (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[        ] (1 failure)
```

The version information is as follows.

Flutter:

```
Flutter 3.10.3 • channel stable • ssh://git@github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f92f44110e (4 days ago) • 2023-06-01 18:17:33 -0500
Engine • revision 2a3401c9bb
Tools • Dart 3.0.3 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

macOS: Ventura 13.4

XCode: 14.3.1

What is the problem?

**What I did**:

First, when I opened `[the directory of the project]/macos/Runner.xcworkspace` in the XCode application and tried building, the build succeeded. At this time, the settings in the Signing & Capabilites tab of XCode are as follows:

- Automatically manage signing: checked
- Team: (my name) (Personal Team)
- Provisioning Profile: Not Required
- Signing Certificate: Sign to Run Locally

I looked at the Settings of the XCode, and there was a valid signing certificates I created.

But when I try to build the project in the terminal, it fails as I described.